# How do I use javascript includes to filter out text that does not include specific text

Tags: javascript, ionic4

I have a method that gets a list of saved photos and determines the number of photos listed.  What I wish to do is return the number of photos that contain the text "Biological Hazards" in the name.  Here is my code so far

```
getPhotoNumber(): void {
  this.storage.get(this.formID+"_photos").then((val) => {
    this.photoResults = JSON.parse(val);
    console.log("photoResults", this.photoResults);
    // photoResults returns 3 photos
      // Hazardscamera_11576868238023.jpg, 
      // Biological Hazardscamera_11576868238023.jpg,
      // Biological Hazardscamera_11576868351915.jpg
    this.photoList = this.photoResults.length;
    console.log("photoList", this.photoList); // returns 3
    this.photoListTwo = this.photoResults.includes('Biological Hazards').length; // I wish to return 2   
  }).catch(err => {
    this.photoList = 0;
  });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Xcode log

[[image: Xcode log[1]]

Comment: You'll need to check each string to see if it includes the text you care about.

Comment: photoResults is an array of 3 strings

Comment: You could [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) `photoResults`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array, and then calculate the length of that array.

```
this.photoListTwo = this.photoResults.filter(photoString => {
 return photoString === 'Biological Hazards' //or whatever comparison makes sense for your data
}).length;
```

Comment: Your answer comes the closest to working but returns 0 for length.  I have added a screenshot of the Xcode log

Comment: I didn't know the format of your string, so you will want to replace `return photoString === 'Biological Hazards'` with `return photoString.includes('Biological Hazards')` Although string.includes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) does not work on IE, so if that is important I would use Rafael's version with test() or include a good polyfill.

Comment: Thank you Sir!  I figured there was an include in there somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution for this (sorry for the lack of better formating, posting from mobile):

```js
const array = ["Hazardscamera_11576868238023.jpg", "Biological Hazardscamera_11576868238023.jpg", "Biological Hazardscamera_11576868351915.jpg"];

const filterBioHazards = (str) => /Biological Hazards/.test(str);

console.log(array.filter(filterBioHazards).length);
// Prints 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `includes` returns `boolean` to indicate whether the array contains a value or not. What you need is to filter your array and return its length after.
You need to replace the line:

```
this.photoListTwo = this.photoResults.includes('Biological Hazards').length;
```

By this:

```
this.photoListTwo = this.photoResults.filter(function(result) {return result.contains("Biological Hazards");}).length;
```